# Capturing Values in Page Source that are not visible elements in Selenium

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a novice Selenium user and wanted to capture some web analytic information. Currently at my company we use Omniture, whose variables and functions to track certain values such as page name are in the javascript. Whenever a page with these anaylytics in their javascript is loaded, you can see what those values equal in the page source. The piece of the page source I want to capture looks as follows:

```
      s.pageName="Vail:home";
      s.channel="";
      s.hier1="Vail,home,";
      OmnitureTracking.pageViewType = 'None'; s.prop1="Vail";
      s.prop2="Vail:home";
      s.prop3="Vail:home:";
      s.prop4="Vail:home:";
      s.prop75="D=v75";
      s.prop73="D=v73";
      s.prop10="D=v10";
      s.prop11="D=v11";
      s.prop7="Logged Out";
      s.eVar75="";
      s.eVar73="";
      s.eVar10="";
      s.eVar11="";
      s.eVar7="D=c7";
      $(document).ready(function() {
```

I would like to use the following command for each value:

```
      String sPageName = driver.findElement(ByLocator).getAttribute("s.pageName");
```

But without a visible locator on the page, what would I locate by?

I also thought about firing off the JavaScript using the following:

```
      String sPageName = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return s.getPageName();");
```

But the omniture javascript code changes from page to page, so upkeep of that script wouldn't be efficient.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you use a variable in the script?  Something like `executeScript("return " + scriptName + ";");`

Comment: Use javascript driver to execute script.